# php mkdir with uniqueid then put files in it

Tags: php, mkdir

```
$unique = uniqid();
$file = 'post.php';
$root = '/' . $dir_auth1 . '/'. $file;
$folder = mkdir($unique); 
$folder5 = $folder . '/' . $file;
$newFolder = '/' . $unique . '/' . $file;
$destination= 'gallry' . '/'  . $unique . '/' . $file;
if($folder) {

echo $newFolder;
copy('file.php', $newFolder);
if (!copy('file.php', $newFolder)) {
    echo "nope.";   
} else {
    echo "Success!";
    echo $newFolder;`

}

}
```

that is my code, right now it is returning nope, along with the `$newFolder` variable because it is being echoed through.
It does not stuff the file in `$newFolder` please help.

Comment: Whats the permissions of the newly created directory? ...and have you got permission to copy to it...?

Comment: @Stuart i didnt know it needed permissions, what 3 digits should I set it to?

Comment: 644 should be safe for files (755 on the directories).

...but without seeing your set up - which users belong to which groups etc, i cant say for sure but you may well be ok with the ones above

Comment: @Stuart can you show me with my code above where they belong?

Comment: Well i'd add 755 to your call to mkdir (if you RTM you'll know that mkdir will default [stupidly] to 777 [wide open]):

    mkdir($theDir, 0755);

This of course means that you would already be able to write to the directories....

Also - as i read your code, it seems you are trying to copy a file to a directory (not INTO a directory) which wont work of course, so you need to specify a new FILE location, not a directory....

    copy($oldFilePath, $newFilePath)

Where $newFile will be INSIDE your newly created directory

I hope that makes sense?

Comment: @Stuart
it makes sense but just go ahead and answer my question with the code revised, and I will upvote if working right :)